# Ionic 3 tabs inside a innerpage of the ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to add tabs inside the inner page of ionic 3.
i need two tabs inside a inner page of my application.
here iam using ion segment button for that purpose but i cant able to change the view when we change the tabs.
how to implement tabs inside a page or any other alternative solution for that.[image: here is the screenshot which i already developed using ion segment button]

Comment: I have similar issue, did you get any solution?
Please read more about my issue at [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-segment-inside-ionic-tab-not-displaying-child-page-properly/176151)

Answer (score 1):

I am using super-tabs instead of ionic default tabs inside my pages (ionic 3).
You can use it in inner page. additionally it can swipe between tabs with smooth speed and scroller. And some features that you cant find it in ionic default tabs for example, badge counter...
Here is [ionic super-tabs](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs) documents. And  [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-swipeable-tabs-to-an-ionic-application/) is a simple example of how you can install it.

Comment: Yeah..i know that..but i need to know that is there any mechanism to implement tabs with ion segment buttons

Comment: Yes, i did that with segment, and with swipe. But it was useless. I will post you as soon as possible

Comment: Could you pls share the code for super tabs inside a innerpage

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-swipeable-tabs-to-an-ionic-application/       it is too easy to test